# map_dfc for every row of dataframe with inputs

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, purrr

I started to learn the usage of "purrr" library and wanted to know how I would go about the following:

**Objective**

Apply a function to every row of the dataframe with inputs as columns, and cbind the function output as a column in the input dataframe

**Idea**

From the documentation it seems map_dfc is the function perfect here

**Attempted Solution**

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

test_func <- function(n, lambda){
  return(n+lambda)
}

n <- seq(1,10,1)
lambda <- seq(1, 10, 1)

new_df <- list(n=n,lambda=lambda) %>% cross_df()

new_df <- map_dfc(new_df, test_func)
# even tried the below
# new_df <- map_dfc(new_df, ~test_func)
```

**Error**

```
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : argument "lambda" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `purrr` way - it seems** - would be the use of `invoke`

```
new_df %>% 
  mutate(new_col = invoke(test_func, new_df))
# A tibble: 100 x 3
#       n lambda new_col
#   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     1      1       2
# 2     2      1       3
# 3     3      1       4
# 4     4      1       5
# 5     5      1       6
# 6     6      1       7
# 7     7      1       8
# 8     8      1       9
# 9     9      1      10
#10    10      1      11
# … with 90 more rows
```

From the help file:

> This pair of functions make it easier to combine a function and list of parameters to get a result. invoke is a wrapper around do.call that makes it easy to use in a pipe.

So `invoke(test_func, new_df)` is the same as

```
test_func(new_df[[1]], new_df[[2]])
```

** The help file also says [image]

---

Without the `purrr` package

```
do.call(test_func, new_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `map2_*` family of functions since you're `walk`ing over two columns:

```
map2_dfc(new_df[1],new_df[2],test_func)
```

**EDIT**
You can achieve the same with `base`'s `Reduce`:

```
 Reduce(test_func,new_df)
 #[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

`purrr` output:
You can rename your column as required:

```
     n
   <dbl>
 1     2
 2     3
 3     4
 4     5
 5     6
 6     7
 7     8
 8     9
 9    10
10    11
```

Comment: The output is correct, but why did the cbind not take place on the new_df. Maybe my understanding of this function is wrong?

Comment: This function `cbind`s the result but discards the original data. You can just add it with `mutate` or just `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Extending what user markus said, `rlang::exec()` can be used like the deprecated `purrr::invoke()`